# Getting horizontally scroll bar but width is 100%

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am beginner. I am trying to create webpage to practice HTML & CSS. I set the width of all of them to 100% but I am getting scroll bar horizontally. I tried a lot to find the problem but I failed.

My code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 89vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 53.7% auto;
    grid-column-gap: 2.2rem;
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
.header-1 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(./twitter-header-2.png) no-repeat center center/cover;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.header-1 > i {
    font-size: 275px;
    color: white;
}
.header-2 {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.header-2 i {
    font-size: 42px;
    color: #1da1f2;
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
.header-2-title {
    font-family: TwitterChirpExtendedHeavy, Verdana, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 64px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 3.2rem;
}
.header-2-subtitle {
    font-family: TwitterChirpExtendedHeavy, Verdana, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 31px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.header-2 a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
.header-2-a-1, .header-2-a-2 {
    width: 64%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding: 13px 0;
    border-radius: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.header-2-a-1 {
    background: #1da1f2;
    color: white;
}
.header-2-a-2 {
    border: 1px solid #1da1f2;
    color: #1da1f2;
    background: transparent;
}
.header-2-a-1:hover {
    background: #1a91da;
}
.header-2-a-2:hover {
    background: #e8f5fe;
}

/* ========================= Footer ========================= */

footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
footer a, footer p {
    color: #5b7083;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer a {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
footer p {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
footer a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

/* ==================== Responsive ==================== */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="icon" href="./twitter-fav.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./fontawesome-free-5.15.3-web/css/all.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-+0n0xVW2eSR5OomGNYDnhzAbDsOXxcvSN1TPprVMTNDbiYZCxYbOOl7+AMvyTG2x" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
    <title>Twitter. It's whats's happening / Twitter</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- ========================= Header ========================= -->
    <header>
        <div class="header-1"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></div>
        <div class="header-2">
            <div class="header-2-contents">
                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                <p class="header-2-title">Happening now</p>
                <p class="header-2-subtitle">Join Twitter today.</p>
                <a href="#"><div class="header-2-a-1">Sign up</div></a>
                <a href="#"><div class="header-2-a-2">Log in</div></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <!-- ========================= Footer ========================= -->
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-1">
            <a href="#" role="button">About</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Help Center</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Terms of Service</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Privacy Policy</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Cookie Policy</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Ads info</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Blog</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Status</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Careers</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Brand Resources</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Advertising</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Marketing</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Twitter for Business</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Developers</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Directory</a>
            <a href="#" role="button">Settings</a>
        </div>
        <div><p>&copy; 2021 Twitter, Inc.</p></div>
    </footer>
    <!-- ========================= JavaScript ========================= -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-gtEjrD/SeCtmISkJkNUaaKMoLD0//ElJ19smozuHV6z3Iehds+3Ulb9Bn9Plx0x4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I remove the scroll bar?
I am getting scroll bar on `inspect mode` but on normal window it seems good.

Where is the problem with my code? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: with the code provided, I can not reproduce the issue you describing. There is no horizontal scrollbar for me.

Comment: Scroll bar is appearing when I go to `inspect` mode.

Answer (score 1):

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 89vh;
    display: flex;      // change this part
    grid-template-columns: 53.7% auto;
    grid-column-gap: 2.2rem;
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Here, change the display property with flex.

Comment: Your solution worked. But it has to be grid. Because for small devices, header-1 has to be moved below header-2.
Is there any way to solve this problem by keeping it grid?

Answer (score 0):

I have found out a solution.
All you have to do is change the display attribute of the header. Liker this:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 89vh;
    display: flex;    // changed from grid
    grid-template-columns: 53.7% auto;
    grid-column-gap: 2.2rem;
    border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Comment: down-voted for following reason: Answer is to broad and unspecific. This Anwser should contain a minimal reproduciable code snippet to show that the answer works. Also explain the issue and how the solution would fix the issue. Where to apply the property.

Comment: Don't post the same answer twice please.